# Argument of type xxx is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | FunctionComponent<any> | ComponentClass<any, any>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am dynamically rendering an array of React icons using Typescript. There is one error I cannot figure out which probably has to do with the type I'm using on the list.

`Argument of type 'IconListProps' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | FunctionComponent<any> | ComponentClass<any, any>'`

Is it a syntax error or something else?

**Component**

```
export const TestIcon: React.FC<
  React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>
> = (props: SvgIconProps) => {
  const { height, width, viewBox } = props;

  const title = props.title ?? 'Title';

  return (
    <SvgIconWrapper
      height={height}
      width={width}
      title={title}
      viewBox={viewBox}
    >
      <path ...
```

**List**

```
import TestIcon from './'

type IconListProps = {
  name: string;
  icon: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
};

export const IconList: IconListProps[] = [
  {
    name: 'TestIcon',
    icon: TestIcon
  }
]
```

**View**

```
import { IconList } from './IconList';

export default function IconsDemo() {
  const icons = IconList.map((item, i) => {
    const TheIcon = item.icon;

    return (
      <div key={`icon-${i}`}>
        <TheIcon /> <span>{item.name}</span>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div>
      {icons}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the server and everything is working. Not sure what type of change would have required a server restart though.